# Can't write to sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing a reddit bot and I'm trying to write to a sqlite3 database but the program just crashes right away. I was following a youtube tutorial and everything has been working up until he started to do stuff with sqlite3.

```
import praw
import sqlite3

USERAGENT = "/u/***** reddit bot"
USERNAME = "*****"
PASSWORD = "*****"
SUBREDDIT = "test"
MAXPOSTS = 10

SETPHRASES = ["python", "bots"]
SETRESPONSE = "I am a python bot."

print('Opening database')
sql = sqlite3.connect('sql.db')
cur = sql.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS oldposts(ID TEXT)')
sql.commit()

print("Logging into Reddit.")
r = praw.Reddit(USERAGENT)
r.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)

def replybot():
    print('Fetching subreddit ' + SUBREDDIT)
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit(SUBREDDIT)
    print('Fetching comments')
    comments = subreddit.get_comments(limit=MAXPOSTS)
    for comment in comments:
        cid = comment.id
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM oldposts WHERE ID=?', [cid]
        if not cur.fetchone():
            try:
                cauthor.lower() = comment.author.name
                if cauthor.lower() != USERNAME.lower():
                    cbody = comment.body.lower()
                    if any(key.lower() in cbody for key in SETPHRASES):
                        print("Replying to " + cauthor)
                        comment.reply(SETRESPONSE)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

            cur.execute('INSERT INTO oldposts VALUES(?)',[cid])
            sql.commit()

replybot()
```

What am I doing wrong? The tutorial I was following said all I had to do was import sqlite3 and it would work.

Comment: What message did it tell you as it crashed?  It had to have said something.

Comment: I worded that poorly. In the tutorial the bot would run through the whole process of this:

Logging into Reddit.
Fetching subreddit
Fetching comments

and saying replying to: if it found a comment to reply to. Now it just doesn't do that.

Comment: My question still stands.  Python would have given you some kind of error message.

Comment: My apologies, I'm new to Python. I just assumed the program crashed because the cmd didn't stay up like it used to do; it just went away as soon as I ran the program and didn't run any of my print statements like it had before.

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors. `if not cur.fetchone():` is one and `cauthor.lower() = comment.author.name` is another. For the second case you cannot assign to a function, instead try `cauthor = comment.author.name.lower()` perhaps.

Comment: Possibly replace `if not cur.fetchone():` with `data = cur.fetchone()
` <newline> `if data is not None:`. Sorry I dont have time to formulate you an answer that I know works.

Comment: I have gotten it to go to "Opening Database", then it closes out again.

Comment: If you run the script from the command line the window doesn't go away after running, and you can read what the error was.

Comment: You just may want to change your reddit password right now, since it's a usable login and can be misused. Never, ever put a password in visible code.

Comment: Don't worry, it was a test account. But I will do that anyways.

Comment: It's probably in your name/email, so in the end, you'll be responsible for it.